# Pandas: What is the best way to 'crop' as large dataframe to only the previous 1000 days?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the index is made up of datetimes. I also have an anchor date and I know that I only want the second dataframe to contain the 1000 days previous to the anchor date. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it's the best way, but it should work

Create example DataFrame:

```
>>> dates = [pd.datetime(2012, 5, 4), pd.datetime(2012, 5, 5), pd.datetime(2012, 5, 6), pd.datetime(2012, 5, 1), pd.datetime(2012, 5, 2), pd.datetime(2012, 5, 3)]
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(values, dates)
>>> df
>>> df
            0
2012-05-04  1
2012-05-05  2
2012-05-06  3
2012-05-01  4
2012-05-02  5
2012-05-03  6
```

Suppose we want 2 days back from 2012-05-04:

```
>>> date_end = pd.datetime(2012, 5, 4)
>>> date_start = date_end - pd.DateOffset(days=2)
>>> date_start, date_end
(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 4, 0, 0))
```

Now let's try to get rows by [label indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label):

```
>>> df.loc[date_start:date_end]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0]
Index: []
```

That's because our index is not sorted, so let's fix it:

```
>>> df.sort_index(inplace=True)
>>> df.loc[date_start:date_end]
            0
2012-05-02  5
2012-05-03  6
2012-05-04  1
```

It's also possible to get rows by [datetime indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#datetime-indexing):

```
>>> df[date_start:date_end]
            0
2012-05-02  5
2012-05-03  6
2012-05-04  1
```

Keep in mind that I'm still not an expert in Pandas, but I like it for Data Analysis very much.

Hope it helps.